A problem in solving ODE generated by wave equation.
The problem is given below:

Find the solution to the equation
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx}=k^2 u
\end{equation}
and the solution has the form $u=f(x^2-c^2 t^2)=f(s)$.
And expand it to a power series of $s$ with the condition $f(0)=1$.

I use the chain rule to write $u_{tt}$ and $u_{xx}$ as the linear combinations of the derivative of $f(x)$. Detailedly,they are formulas below:
\begin{equation}
u_t=-2c^2tf'(x^2-c^2t^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_x=2xf'
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}=4c^4t^2f''-2ct^2f'
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_{xx}=4x^2f''+2f'
\end{equation}
I substitute them in the raw equation and then get:
\begin{equation}
4c^4t^2f''-2c^2f'-4c^2x^2f''-2c^2f'=k^2f
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
4c^2sf''-4c^2f'=k^2f
\end{equation}
Now I have to solve the ODE.But I don't have the method.How should I forge to the next step?

When substituting the ansatz I found a sign difference from the equation in the problem statement. Also rearranging gives:
$$s f''(s) + f'(s) + \left(\frac{k}{2 c}\right)^2 f(s) = 0 .$$
Hint Setting $s := \left(\frac{c r}{k}\right)^2$ transforms the equation to the Bessel equation of order $0$: $$r^2 f''(r) + r f(r) + r^2 f(r) = 0 ,$$
the general solution of which is
$$f(r) = a J_0(r) + b Y_0(r),$$
where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions of the first and second kind (both of order $0$), respectively.

The condition $f(0) = 1$ imposes $a = 1$, $b = 0$, so $f(r) = J_0(r) ,$ hence $$\boxed{f(s) = J_0\left(\frac{k \sqrt s}{c}\right)} .$$

The Maclaurin series of $J_0(r)$ is
$$f(r) \sim \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!^2 4^m} r^{2 m} = 1 - \frac14 r^2 + \frac1{64} r^4 - \frac1{2304} r^6 + \cdots .$$

I got it.Thank you for your help.

You're welcome.
